# Cordova abrir links do app dentro do app

Tags: apache-cordova, navegador-de-internet

Eu tenho um site responsivo, criei um app com cordova rodando a partir desse site, porém quando clico nos links, ele tá jogando pra fora do app, no navegador do celular. Quero que ele fique rodando dentro do app, alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a melhor solução no seu caso seria trabalhar com um `<iframe></iframe>`. O cordova nada mais é que um navegador que roda um "site" local e dá acesso a uma série de funções do celular para ele. Se você tenta "abrir" uma nova aba, ele não irá manter o controle sobre a app e terá que forçar uma abertura em um navegador (cordova não tem abas).

Sendo assim, se você abrisse um modal que ocupa a tela toda por exemplo, e nele tivesse um iframe com seu conteúdo, você ainda estaria na "mesma aba".

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver apenas tirando a barra final da url no content src do config.xml, por mais idiota que possa ser, isso resolveu meu problema.

Ex: www.seusite.com/ não tava indo
www.seusite.com funcionou.

abraços